# PDFBox - text align to the right

Tags: java, pdfbox

I am here again because of pdfbox. I want do something from this text:

```
A
AS
ASD
ASDF
```

to this:

```
    A
   AS
  ASD
 ASDF
```

How can I do that alligment?

Comment: Is it possible? This would very simplify my doc and generate variables with less lines of code

Comment: It is possible to right-align text. You merely have to calculate the width of the text and then start drawing the text at (right_border_y_coordinate - width)

Comment: You can get the width of a string with `PDFont.getStringWidth()`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on others answers around similar questions, I wrote the following code which is working fine.

```java
public static void drawTextMultilineRightAlign(final PDPageContentStream content,
                                               final PDFont font,
                                               final int fontSize,
                                               final float leadingSpace,
                                               final float x,
                                               final float y,
                                               final String... texts) throws IOException {
    content.setFont(font, fontSize);
    content.setLeading(leadingSpace);
    content.beginText();
    int i = 0;
    for(final String text : texts) {
        content.setTextMatrix(Matrix.getTranslateInstance(x - getStringWidth(text, font, fontSize), y + i * leadingSpace));
        content.showText(text);
        content.newLine();
    }
    content.endText();
}

// Found somewhere else on stackoverflow
public  static float getStringWidth(final String text, final PDFont font, final int fontSize) throws IOException {
    return font.getStringWidth(text) * fontSize / 1000.f;
}
```